# Magento Widget does not appear on Newsletter

Tags: php, magento, widget, newsletter

I am having a trouble on Magento CE 1.7 when dealing with Newsletters.

I was trying to put a Widget inside my Newsletter Template, but unfortunately it's not showing when rendering the preview or while receiving the Email.

Widgets are they supported onto Newsletter Templates ?
Am i having an issu, does it depend on configuration or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your template:

```
<?php
 $filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
 $_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="2"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>
```